# MongoDB "filtered" index: is it possible?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Is it possible to index some documents of the collection "only if" one of the fields to be indexed has a particular value?

Let me explain with an example:

The collection "posts" has millions of documents, ALL defined as follows:

```
    {
        "network": "network_1",
        "blogname": "blogname_1",
        "post_id": 1234,
        "post_slug": "abcdefg"
    }
```

Let's assume that the distribution of the post is equally split on network_1 and network_2

My application OFTEN select the type of query based on the value of "network" (although sometimes I need the data from both networks):

For example:

```
www.test.it/network_1/blog_1/**postid**/1234/
 -> db.posts.find ({network: "network_1" blogname "blog_1", post_id: 1234})

www.test.it/network_2/blog_4/**slug**/aaaa/
 -> db.posts.find ({network: "network_2" blogname "blog_4" post_slug: "yyyy"})
```

I could create two separate indexes (network / blogname / post_id and network / blogname / post_slug) but I would get a huge waste of RAM, since 50% of the data in the index will never be used.

Is there a way to create an index "filtered"?

Example:
(Note the WHERE parameter)

```
db.posts.ensureIndex ({network: 1 blogname: 1, post_id: 1}, {where: {network: "network_1"}})

db.posts.ensureIndex ({network: 1 blogname: 1, post_slug: 1}, {where: {network: "network_2"}})
```

Comment: This is not yet possible in MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but it requires a workaround which creates redundancy in your documents, requires you to rewrite your find-queries and limits find-queries to exact matches.

MongoDB supports [sparse indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-sparse) which only index the documents where the given field  exists. You can use this feature to only index a part of the collection by adding this field only to those documents you want to index.

The bad news is that sparse indexes can only include a single field. But the good news is, that this field can also contain an object with multiple fields, so you can still store all the data you want to search for in this field.

To do this, add a new field to the included documents which includes an object with the fields you search for:

```
{
    "network": "network_1",
    "blogname": "blogname_1",
    "post_id": 1234,
    "post_slug": "abcdefg"
    "network_1_index_key": {
        "blogname": "blogname_1",
        "post_id": 1234
    }
}
```

Your ensureIndex command would index the field network_1_index_key:

```
 db.posts.ensureIndex( { network_1_index_key: 1 }, { sparse: true } )
```

A find-query which is supposed to use this index, must now query for the exact object of the field network_1_index_key:

```
 db.posts.find ({ 
                    network_1_index_key: { 
                        blogname: "blogname_1", 
                        post_id: 1234 
                    } 
                })
```

Doing this would likely only make sense when the documents you want to index are a very small part of the collection. When its about half, I would just create a regular index and live with it because the larger document-size could mitigate the gains from the reduced index size.

Comment: I think your suggestion is now the only possible solution, but I need to update millions of existing documents and check if working set will fit in RAM

Comment: @Ligio Maybe some server-sided javascript could do the job? When you encounter any problems with transforming lots of documents, you should create a new question.

Comment: This answer is deprecated with the introduction of `partialFilterExpression ` (see other answers, MongoDB 3.2+)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it's possible in MongoDB 3.2+ They call it   **partialFilterExpression** where you can set a condition based on which index will be created.

**Example**

```
db.users.createIndex({ "userId": 1, "project": 1 }, 
{ unique: true, partialFilterExpression:{ 
  userId: { $exists: true, $gt : { $type : 10 } } } })
```

Please see [Partial Index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraint) documentation

Answer (score 1):

As of MongoDB v3.2, partial indexes are supported.  Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/

Answer (score -3):

You can try create index on all field (network / blogname / post_id / post_slug)

Comment: But that would be exactly what Ligio wanted to avoid.

Comment: The index "network / blogname / post_id / post_slug" will not cover a find on "network / blogname / post_slug"

Comment: I created the same index on my collection, and it works for me. Can you send info about your collection? db.posts.stats() and db.posts.find ({network: "network_1" blogname "blog_1", post_id: 1234}).explain() ?

Comment: Philipp, Ligio wanted to avoid creating two indexes.